# Resize buttons with window resizing

Tags: css, resize

I have made two rows of buttons (with letters A-Z). Css code for buttons and rows is:

```
.buttons{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #009999;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0.2em ;
  margin: 0.1em;
  
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
 
} 
.firstRow, .secondRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:  row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90%;
}
```

When I resize the window, I want these buttons to resize according to the size of the window as well.
My problem is that when I reduce the size of the window, the letters remain the same size and they are not all shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `vw(viewport)` instead of `em`

```css
 .buttons{
     display: flex;
     background-color: #009999;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 0.3em;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     width: 5vw;
     height: 5vw;
     font-size: 1.5vw;
     padding: 2%;
     margin: 1%;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bold;
}
 .firstRow, .secondRow {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: center;
     padding: 0.2rem;
     list-style-type: none;
     width: 90%;
}
```